# issue with #yammer iOS SDK

Tags: ios, safari, yammer

Just got a review by Apple team today stating that my app will be rejected because of the Yammer SSO implementation.

Am quoting "We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect: Upon launching the app, a web page in mobile Safari opens for logging in Yammer, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able to log in without opening Safari first."

I replied explaining that this is how the Yammer iOS Sdk works and directed them to the official Yammer docs:  https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-sdk

Yammer docs "During the login process, users will be directed to the mobile Safari web browser to complete the OAuth handshake. In order for the browser to be able to switch back to your iOS app after the handshake is done, the custom URL Scheme from above should be registered in the iOS application."

- Am I the only one facing this issue?
- is there a different approach to implement SSO?

Thanks folks.

Comment: Sorry to hear your app was rejected, we're working on a fix for this that will keep the SSO flow login inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

This branch should fix your problem, it uses a UIWebView to complete the SSO flow:

https://github.com/yammer/ios-yammer-sdk/tree/sso_refactor